# How Add tabs and pages on TFS Web Access 2013?

Tags: tfs, extensibility, tfs-sdk

I'm using TFS 2013 with Team Web Access and I want to create custom tab on TWA. It is possible because [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/videos/) has some functionality (they've added custom tabs).

How I add custom tab to TWA? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Urban Tutle uses a couple of undocumented ways and they actually drop a ASP.NET HttpModule in the Web Access process in which they "insert" their custom content. There is no officially supported way to do this at the moment provided by Microsoft.  So if you decide to take a similar approach, you  might have to fix any issues each time Microsoft releases a new Service Pack, Update or Hotfix.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Any resource related to this topic?

Comment: Nothing official. There are a number of samples on StackOverflow on how to do post processing using an Http Module. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6061336/736079 as well as external resources like: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx.